# Server 2019 - Task Scheduler tasks stop running

Tags: scheduled-task, windows-server-2019

I have a set of about 5 tasks that have been running correctly for over a month on a 1 minute and 5-minute basis.    Today at 4 pm, they stopped running, all of them, for no apparent reason.  I can trigger them manually, and they'll run to completion.  I can see the time "Next Run" increment correctly, but the "Last Run" date/time never update unless the task is triggered manually, so I am assuming that they are not running.  These are command-line EXE apps, and I have tested them outside of the task scheduler and they work fine.  They run under my user account in task scheduled, and have been working for a while now.

This happened once before, and I had to recreate all of them and assign them to a different user to run under.  That seemed to have fixed it last time, but did not work this time.  No idea why they would stop being executed.  Does anyone have any troubleshooting steps that I can take?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the event viewer say?

Comment: Not seeing anything specific to the task scheduler.

Comment: Depending on what the tasks are running their may be entries, not for TS, but for the application or process triggered. What are the tasks that are being run? Your question really needs some more information before we can begin to help, information only you can provide.